# CSS How to Make Horizontal Menu Bar stretch across full page width

Tags: css, menu, mouseover, navbar, stretch

I am making a website for a friend and am struggling with the CSS for the menu bar. I've deisgned it as he asked etc., but am having a couple of problems.

1) I can't get it to stretch across the full width of the page. The menu itself should stretch across the whole width of the page, with the width of the page split into 6, and the text in each menu item to be centralised and stay the same size and just add extra black background to accommodate the page width. (Most users who'll be looking at it will be using 1920 x 1080 apparently)
Like so (Ignore the boxes at the top - they were just colour tests):
http://i58.tinypic.com/1z2zkf8.png

2) When I mouseover the menuitems for the submenu, the main menu readjusts itself. How can I stop it doing this, so it stays at a static width for the menu buttons? (i.e. 1/6th of the page width)

3) How can I make it so clicking the main menu will show the relevant submenu and keep it up until there is a click elsewhere on the page (i.e. so you don't have to hold your mouseover to select the submenu)

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Navigation</title>
<link href="navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="clan.html">Clan</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="aboutus.html">Really? You made a website for this?</a></li>
            <li><a href="roster.html">Member Roster</a></li>
            <li><a href="join us.html">One of us...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="games.html">Games</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="gameslist.html">Current Games Rotation</a></li>
            <li><a href="buylist.html">Games You Really Need To Buy</a></li>
            <li><a href="steamlist.html">Clan Steam Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="the_gaz_cave.html">Wargame Decks</a></li>
            <li><a href="gamerandomiser.html">Leon's Wheel o' Games</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="thursday.html">Thursday Game Night</a></li>
            <li><a href="ilan.html">ILAN</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="donate.html">Donate</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="paypal.html">Help Us Not Be Poor</a></li>
            <li><a href="easyfund.html">Help Us Even If You're Poor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="othershit.html">Other Shit</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="links.html">Links to Shit</a></li>
            <li><a href="takemymoney.html">Cheap as Shit Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="stats.html">Stats 'n' Shit</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads.html">Downloadable Shit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
 @import url("AEnigma_Scrawl/stylesheet.css");
.navbar {
    font-family: "AEnigma Scrawl";
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}
.navbar ul {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar ul li {
    float: left;
}
.navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    background-image: url(bg_navbar.png);
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover  , .navbar ul li a:active, .navbar ul li a:focus{
    background-image: url(bg_navbar_hover.png);
}
.navbar ul li a.current {
    background-image: url(bg_navbar_current.png);
}
.navbar ul li .subnav   {
    display: none;
}
.navbar ul li .subnav li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar ul li .subnav li a {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.navbar ul li:hover ul.subnav {
    display: block;
    position: static;
}
.navbar ul li:hover ul.subnav a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your menubar isn't stretching across the page is probably because browsers usually automatically add a margin to the html/body. Try setting this css:

```
 html,
 body
 {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }
```

Also the reason why your menu bar is shifting is because you're positioning the `.subnav ul` as `static` when it should be positioned as `absolute`. Like so:

```
 .navbar ul li .subnav
 {
 position:absolute;
 }
```

Positioning an element as absolute means it takes up no space on page so this means it won't push other elements away.

Comment: I've implemented both of these changes. The menu is still not stretching for some reason - I'm doing this mostly off dreamweaver's live view.

.navbar ul li .subnav changing position didn't do much, but changing .navbar ul li:hover ul.subnav 's position to absolute definitely helped. The menu no longer shifts, however I have gained a side-effect that the submenu now stretches across the entire page width, when really I just want the submenu outer box to be as long as the longest line in that submenu. Thanks you for the suggestions, any ideas on the stretching problems?

Comment: The reason why you changing .navbar ul li .subnav to absolute didn't work is because it was overridden by the hover effect where you applied position static. It's better practice to specify the position on the actual element than on hover.

Comment: Furthermore in your css you say `.navbar ul {width:100%}` this gives any ul element inside the navbar class 100% width. Also it is set to display block which will automatically make it stretch out to 100% width if you don't set the width. Try setting the width for the .subnav class. If you need more help please try to recreate the problem you're having on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `min-width: 100%` on the navbar.
Also change the menu background from image to color.

Comment: min-width: 100% in the navbar class made no difference. Will change the image to colour once I get home.

navbar class now looks like:
 .navbar {
    font-family:"AEnigma Scrawl";
    font-size: 32px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
}